# Fresh eyes needed with Apigee API and Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, apigee

I have just started building my first API through API Management tool and I'm having some problems I'm hoping you can help me with.

My main goal is to have this API work with my mobile app and the Usergrid BAAS by creating calls to the API that link to external Javascript files I have uploaded. My experience so far is that my code worked the first day I tried it, but that exact same code starting breaking the next day, this is very confusing.

PS- I upload the RemoteController.js file as a Node type

Here is my very simple code, I hope you help me spot the issues causing the errors

Test Links:

http://jerryhamby-test.apigee.net/vdex-baas/hello

http://jerryhamby-test.apigee.net/vdex-baas/helloworld

============= my server-usergrid.js code ===========

```
var argo = require('argo');
var express = require('express');
var usergrid = require('usergrid');
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFileSync('./RemoteController.js','utf8');

var app = express();
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

var proxy = argo()
    .target('https://api.usergrid.com')
    .build();

app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello from Express2');
});


app.get('/helloworld', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  RemoteController.helloWorld(req, res);
});

app.all('*', proxy.run);
app.listen(3000);
```

============= my RemoteController.js code ===========

```
function RemoteController() {
}

var client = new usergrid.client({
    orgName:'myOrg',
    appName:'sandbox',
    logging: true, //optional - turn on logging, off by default
    buildCurl: true
});

// test of helloworld
RemoteController.helloWorld = function(req, res) { 
        res.send('RemoteController inside helloWorld');
};
```

============= the error I get when calling RemoteController.helloWorld ===========

```
at /organizations/jerryhamby/environments/test/apis/vDex-BaaS/server-usergrid.js:35
(anonymous) at /node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164 (callbacks) at  
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138 (param) at
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145 (pass) at
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:90 (anonymous) at
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33 (router) at
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193 (next) at
/organizations/grangaswamy/environments/test/apis/apigee-aws/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:97 (multipart) at
/organizations/grangaswamy/environments/test/apis/apigee-aws/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:64 (anonymous) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:41 (urlencoded) at 
/organizations/grangaswamy/environments/test/apis/apigee-aws/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:62 (anonymous) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:42 (json) at 
/organizations/grangaswamy/environments/test/apis/apigee-aws/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:60 (bodyParser) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193 (next) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js:158 (logger) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193 (next) at 
/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:30 (expressInit) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193 (next) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js:45 (query) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193 (next) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:201 (anonymous) at 
/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:65 (app) at 
/Users/Apigee/src/noderunner/target/checkout/node10/node10src/src/main/javascript/io/apigee/trireme/node10/node/events.js:98 (anonymous) at 
/Users/Apigee/src/noderunner/target/checkout/node10/node10src/src/main/javascript/io/apigee/trireme/node10/trireme/adaptorhttp.js:509 (anonymous) at 
/Users/Apigee/src/noderunner/target/checkout/node10/node10src/src/main/javascript/io/apigee/trireme/node10/node/domain.js:183 (anonymous) at 
/Users/Apigee/src/noderunner/target/checkout/node10/node10src/src/main/javascript/io/apigee/trireme/node10/node/domain.js:123 (anonymous) at 
/Users/Apigee/src/noderunner/target/checkout/node10/node10src/src/main/javascript/io/apigee/trireme/node10/trireme/adaptorhttp.js:508 (anonymous) at 
/Users/Apigee/src/noderunner/target/checkout/node10/node10src/src/main/javascript/io/apigee/trireme/node10/trireme/adaptorhttp.js:578 (anonymous)
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using fs.readFileSync instead of `var RemoteController = require('./RemoteController');`?

Comment: Did you deploy with Express in your node_modules bundle? Make sure you've installed 3.4.8 or earlier (`npm install express@3.4.8`) otherwise Express will blow up due to conflicting versions on the Edge platform.

Comment: I'm simple so new at Node.js that I don't know about your require suggestion. I'm just searching online and trying code that I find. Any good links would be a big help. Will test your suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: and to @generalhenry's point, you should use module.exports instead of including via FRS

Comment: package.json is: {
    "name":"usergrid-node",
    "version":"0.0.0",
    "description":"Usergrid Proxy",
    "main":"server-usergrid.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "express":"3.x.x",
        "usergrid":"x.x.x",
        "argo":"x.x.x"
    }
}

Comment: OK, so I suspect you've got a conflicting Express version. From your main packages.json folder, run `npm uninstall express` and then again `npm install express@3.4.8`

Answer (score 0):

Each node module (file ~= module) has it's own context.  You can export variables from that context and require them into your context.

Try this:

============= my server-usergrid.js code ===========

```
var argo = require('argo');
var express = require('express');
var RemoteController = require('./RemoteController');

var app = express();
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

var proxy = argo()
    .target('https://api.usergrid.com')
    .build();

app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello from Express2');
});


app.get('/helloworld', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  RemoteController.helloWorld(req, res);
});

app.all('*', proxy.run);
app.listen(3000);
```

============= my RemoteController.js code ===========

```
var usergrid = require('usergrid');

function RemoteController() {
}

var client = new usergrid.client({
    orgName:'myOrg',
    appName:'sandbox',
    logging: true, //optional - turn on logging, off by default
    buildCurl: true
});

// test of helloworld
RemoteController.helloWorld = function(req, res) { 
        res.send('RemoteController inside helloWorld');
};

module.exports = RemoteController;
```

Comment: BINGO we have a winner! Thanks @generalhenry you saved me lots of hair pulling, now I just need to study modules to understand why this works.

Comment: You can think of each module being it's own function that returns module.exports